# How to import JSON file to create new connections in Oracle SQL developer Version 17.2.0.188

Tags: json, xml, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a JSON file which was shared by someone which contains connection information to different databases. But my current version of SQL developer can only use .xml and .properties file formats to import connections.

Is there a way to import JSON file without updating SQL developer or can I convert this JSON file in any way to XML or PROPERTIES file?

Comment: I'm in a similar situation.  Can you show the json format that you have already (w/o security info)?

Comment: Mods are  removing my answers from other posts. 
 
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer-command-line/23.2/sqcug/import-connections.html#GUID-05EB003F-4BA6-4729-A091-3A85B5EA0419

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your SQL Developer to the latest and greatest, then import your connections.

> Is there a way to import JSON file without updating SQL developer

No.